In retrospect, should they have provided more RTG fuel and a more powerful radio for Voyager?
Adding extra RTG fuel disks would increase the weight of the entire vessel only slightly, but give it a much, much longer lifetime.
It would also allow for the instruments to still be running, and for a more powerful transmitter. Right now it's broadcasting at 25 watts. Is there's some reason they couldn't have added RTG fuel and be broadcasting at a kilowatt? My understanding is that the hydrazine RCS fuel is not an issue.
I know they changed the mission in the middle, and I know they were only designing for inside the solar system.
But they also knew that the mission was likely to be extended, like all missions. And they knew it was a once in a lifetime chance to get information about the outer solar system.

If we had it to do over again, would we beef up Voyager's power from the start?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The "answer" is as much about human nature rather than the nature of the designers of this particular mission.

There are often loosely declared motives for doing a government
mission in the first place, though given they had decided to go ahead
there comes a point very early on in a project's conception where
there has to be a specific reason for everything on a space mission,
the more so the more expensive it is.
Humans, as a whole, don't have a great track record for looking far
ahead. People who do that tend to be dismissed for going against the
grain, unless they have lots of money.
It was launched ~48 years ago, that is a long time for any space
mission.

Speculation:

I doubt the notion of the mission being extended was that prominent
in their minds during design in the early 70s.

There probably wouldn't have been much confidence that the satellite
would still be operating by that time. Its possible the design was to provide enough power for the
foreseeable life of the vehicle.

You can call it short sighted, but relative to what? Not so much
compared to  the rest of humanity.

They could have done it differently but that takes us back to the
first point about motives for a space mission. There is a structural issue about how projects are organised. The designers who
sorted out these problems were not in the room when their bosses'
bosses' bosses committed to the project, they probably never even met
them.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

the ISS is satellite,  Voyager is an interstellar spacereaft


“Adding extra RTG fuel disks would increase the weight of the entire
vessel only slightly, but give it a much, much longer lifetime.”

This statement is not correct. More isotope would increase RTG weight exponentially for a linear increase in mission duration.
Increasing the capacity of an RTG is not just a matter of adding fuel. An RTG depends on the temperature difference between the radioisotope and the heat sink. If the heat sink is inadequately sized, higher temperature will speed up heat aging of the thermocouple at the same time it reduces the potential power output.
Even without the heat sink issue, adding more isotope would not increase longevity linearly the same way that increasing fuel supply would increase the run time of a ICE generator. Isotope heat output follows an exponential decay curve due to the half-life of the isotope. The flip side is that isotope mass at launch must increase exponentially to maintain power output at a given time in the mission.
Double mission length would increase RTG mass 4X, triple mission length increases RTG mass 8x etc.

Also, your power requirements ought to increase (roughly) with the square of time, since the strength of the radio signal follows an inverse-square law. It's not enough to have the current level of power when you're further out, you need more.

@ Cadence ... Good point. Or you could increase the size of the antenna which would have a similarly scaled mass penalty

That would happen when you add more Pu-238 to the existing RTGs, but it's unlikely they would have chosen that route. The Voyager RTGs are cylinders with fins on the sides of the cylinder. 3 RTG units are placed on top of each other, so each RTG has its own heat sink. Adding more power would be done by stacking more RTG units on top.

@Hobbes well that's even worse, then instead of 3 RTGs that will stop being usable in a few years you have 12 RTGs that will stop being usable in a few years. No, for longer mission lifetime you actually should redesign the RTGs themselves, and preferably use a different isotope with longer half-life.

No. After 50 years, you'd have 12 RTGs producing 70 W each for a total of 840 W, instead of 3 RTGs producing 70 W each for a total of 210 W. No matter how much fuel you pack, Pu-238 decay means that after 50 years you have half the original power left.

@Hobbes The way the RTG stack is just jutting out of the side of Voyager makes me less than sanguine that you could quadruple its size and mass without some structural issues.

You're more likely end up with 3 or 4 groups of RTGs, each on a short boom, pointing in different directions. Although that would lead to new problems positioning the instruments. But the point remains: due to the square-cube law, you can't make RTGs a lot fatter without running into cooling problems or having to add a cooling loop with radiators away from the RTG.

The power output of the rtg actually drops slightly slower than an expance because the temperature gradient increases. But this is just nitpicking

Yes, there is a reason: adding more RTGs would have made the Voyagers too heavy to be launched on the trajectory they used.
The RTGs weigh 50 kg for 150 W of power at launch, IIRC. IRL they had 3 RTGs for 470 W at launch.
Broadcasting at 1 kW now (when 220 W is available after 50 years of decay) would require 12-15 RTG modules.

Was enough pu-238 even available at time of launch? In recent history the amount of material has dictated RTG size and number but they were running more reactors then.

IIRC the space program's RTGs were basically using waste material from nuclear weapon development (essentially "depleted plutonium"), so they had a functionally unlimited supply.  Today we don't have active nuke construction going on so there's only what's left over.

Or, put differently, what instruments would have been deleted in order to fit all the RTGs in. At some point one would have no instruments and be launching a giant space heater.

that made my day: mission profile "space heater" :)

@DarthPseudonym no. The Ph-238 used in US RTGs is not a waste product and has to be manufactured separately.

Well, okay the Pu-238 is made by neutron bombardment of Np-237, but the neptunium was coming out of Hanford, wasn't it? Which is nuclear weapon production.

Additional weight would have come from the radiators needed to dump all that excess heat, and structural elements to keep the whole thing in one piece.

@Cadence and from the extra propellant needed to manage all that extra weight

@DarthPseudonym Yes, Hanford was producing Np-237. But it's not a waste product, more like a side product. Np-237 mostly comes from U-235, so if you're already churning out U-235 and have a handy breeder reactor it's feasible to make some Np-237. OTOH, extracting Np-237 from the waste of a natural uranium power reactor is a pain because that waste has a lot of short half-life isotopes that emit nasty beta & gamma radiation. I have some info on Np-237 in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/717587/123208 & info on Pu-238 in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/705112/123208

@PM2Ring and while you can extract Np237 (and whatever other isotopes you want) from nuclear waste, current laws and regulations regarding the handling and disposal of nuclear waste prohibit doing so. This is very short sighted as reprocessing waste can help isolate out short and long half life elements, thus greatly reducing the storage cost (and time) for the majority of the waste, and giving potentially useful materials for for example RTGs, nuclear medicine, and other applications.

@planetmaker It was the celestial objects that made us all this plutonium, after all. It's time we gave something back.

@Sneftel Ok, neutron star mergers produce some plutonium, but only a very tiny amount of that primordial Pu remains, due to its short half-life. A tiny amount of Pu is produced by neutron absorption in uranium ores, but virtually all of our Pu is synthetically produced from uranium. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium

@jwenting Ehhh. That restriction I get -- it's basically impossible to distinguish "we're extracting useful stuff out of our spent fuel rods" from "we're extracting weapons-grade material for building bombs" so we made a lot of agreements to just not do that at all.

@DarthPseudonym that's the reason it was done, and it's largely bogus. Sure you can extract Plutonium but it will need a lot of work to make weapons grade, requiring large detectable facilities (how we found the Iranian and North Korean programs). That Plutonium can however also be used as fuel for other reactors, greatly reducing the total waste output and cost of running the program. That fear was planted deliberately by the KGB in the 1980s btw, in an effort (somewhat successful) to make the general public think that all nuclear power stations are nuclear bombs.


But they also knew that the mission was likely to be extended, like all missions.

Like all what missions, exactly? Voyager 1 was initially planned as Mariner 11. By the time it flew, all other Mariners were already dead.
I made a list of US solar-system exploratory missions (pioneer, mariner, ranger, viking) up to the launch of Voyager 1, showing durations from launch until last transmission or destruction, and for those that were still alive in 1977, I've put in bold how long they'd been alive and added what their power source was. My "launch failure" includes failure to separate, etc. For fairness and completeness's sake, I've also included satellites, where they were RTG-powered.

1958: Pioneer 0: launch failure
1958: Pioneer 1: launch failure
1958: Pioneer 2: launch failure
1958: Pioneer 3: launch failure
1959: Pioneer 4: 4 days
1959: Pioneer P-1: launch failure
1959: Pioneer P-3: launch failure
1960: Pioneer 5 (P-2): 3 months
1960: Pioneer P-30: launch failure
1960: Pioneer P-31: launch failure
1961: (sat) Transit-4A: 16 of >63 years, still going - 1st RTG sat, US Navy
1961: (sat) Transit-4B: 16 of >63 years, still going - RTG sat
1961: Ranger 1: launch failure
1961: Ranger 2: launch failure
1962: Ranger 3: 2 days
1962: Ranger 4: 5 days
1962: Ranger 5: 1 day
1962: Mariner 1: launch failure
1962: Mariner 2: 5 months
1963: (sat) Transit 5BN-1: 14 of >61 years, still going - RTG sat
1963: (sat) Transit 5BN-2: 14 of >61 years, still going - RTG sat
1964: Mariner 3, launch failure
1964: Mariner 4: 3 years
1964: Ranger 6: 4 days
1964: Ranger 7: 3 days
1964: (sat) Transit 5BN-3, launch failure - RTG sat
1965: Ranger 8: 4 days
1965: Ranger 9: 4 days
1965: Pioneer 6 (A): 12 of 35 years - solar
1965: (sat) SNAPSHOT: 12 of >59 years, still going - RTG sat
1966: Pioneer 7 (B): 11 of 29 years - solar
1967: Pioneer 8 (C): 10 of 29 years - solar
1967: Mariner 5: 5 months
1968: Pioneer 9 (D): 9 of 25 years - solar
1968: (sat) Nimbus B (Nimbus-B1): launch failure - RTG sat
1969: Pioneer E: launch failure
1969: Mariner 6: <2 years
1969: Mariner 7: <2 years
1969: (sat) Nimbus 3 (Nimbus-B2): <3 years - First NASA RTG sat
1969: Apollo 11 (EASEP): N/A - RT passive heaters
1969: Apollo 12 (ALSEP 1): 8 of 8? years - RTG Lunar experiment
1970: (sat) Nimbus IV, 1970: 7 of <11 years - RTG sat
1970: Apollo 13 (ALSEP *): 5 days - RTG Lunar experiment
1971: Mariner 8: launch failure
1971: Mariner 9: <2 years
1971: Apollo 14 (ALSEP 3): 6 of 6? years - RTG Lunar experiment
1971: Apollo 15 (ALSEP 2): 6 of 6? years - RTG Lunar experiment
1972: Pioneer 10 (F): 5 of 31 years - RTG
1972: Apollo 16 (ALSEP 4): 5 of 5? years - RTG Lunar experiment
1972: Apollo 17 (ALSEP 5): 5 of 5? years - RTG Lunar experiment
1972: (sat) TRAID-01-1X: 5 of >52 years, still going - RTG sat
1972: (sat) Nimbus V: 5 of 11 years - RTG sat
1973: Pioneer 11 (G): 4 of 22 years - RTG
1973: Mariner 10: <2 years
1975: (sat) Nimbus VI: 2 of 8 years - RTG sat
1976: Viking 1 Orbiter: 1 of <5 years - solar
1976: Viking 1 Mars Lander: 1 of <7 years - RTG
1976: Viking 2 Orbiter: 1 of <2 years - solar
1976: Viking 2 Mars Lander: 1 of <4 years - RTG
1976: (sat) LES-8: 1 of >48 years, still going  - RTG sat
1976: (sat) LES-9: 1 of >48 years, still going  - RTG sat
Voyager 1 (Mariner 11), 1977: - >47 years, still going - RTG

Now, I'm cherry-picking, showing only stuff from the US NASA's own probes, and omitting any non-interplanetary spacecraft which lacked RTG.
Still, it's clear that no interplanetary probe missions had, by this point, been extended. Even the four solar-powered Pioneer craft set to study solar weather were still well within their mission specifications, and they didn't have RTGs. The Apollo ALSEP experiments left on the moon were the only extended missions I could find, as they had a planned operating duration of one year. But even all their experiments would be terminated and turned off 25 days after Voyager 1 launched (they were left transmitting the carrier frequency, though, so continued transmitting carrier frequencies for an unknown number of years afterwards).
Overall, there was nothing at this point to suggest that interplanetary spacecraft would last into the next century, let alone for a half-century.
What basis could they have had for imagining such astonishing duration? This was only the third interplanetary mission with RTG power, and the others had only been going for 5 years by launch, likely far less at the time the design was being thought up.
In the late 1970s, a lot of technologies that have since plateaued were then on a rapid, even exponential rise. At least in the common imagination, our then-current rocketry technologies were expected to be completely superseded by the year 2000, and in 2020 we anticipated that we'd be zooming about in jetpacks, flying cars, and spacecraft on the regular. It was all unimaginably far in the future. The first flight of the Space Shuttle still four years away, and that was just the first step to our inevitable path to the stars.
We hadn't realized yet what having flown our last mission to the moon meant, in terms of space exploration. We didn't even know that it was our last mission there: to the designers of spacecraft in the 70s, the idea that we might never return to the moon in their lifetimes was both unimagined and unimaginable.
These probes were designed for one purpose, and that was to do some planetary flybys. By 2020, obviously, we'd be visiting those planets in person, with our ion-drives, launching from our rotating space stations or a moonbase, perhaps using nuclear ram-drives to blast across the solar system in days. The propulsion technology was not expected to stagnate. The flow of multiple probes a year was not expected to dry up.
In 1977, given how much the probes were increasing in sophistication, the idea that it would still be worth extending the mission of the very early ones to more than 50 years, was near unthinkable.
There wasn't really thought to be anything particularly worthwhile for the probes to study once their flyby mission of finished. The idea, made famous by Star Trek: The Motion Picture, was just to cast them out into space as a postcard to any aliens who might find them.
And there's no real point in powering a postcard.

But you also ask not just "should they", but also the secondary question of "would we", if we were to do it all over again, with the benefit of hindsight, knowing as we now do that the components could and would survive essentially indefinitely, and that this experiment in particular wouldn't blow up on the launchpad nor die quickly so we needed to get as much info as we could as fast as we could from it... I think it might arguably be worth the extra radioactive fuel. But as others have pointed out, that might then mean a cost in weight, and hence a tradeoff against the shortest-lived instrumentation.
And the engineers back then were right. There's not a LOT out there in interstellar space to study. So any tradeoff of more years of that very lightweight information density, compared to the insights the instruments gave us on their primary, high-information-density mission of planetary science, is likely not worth the cost.

RTG fuel isn't the limiting factor for the life of the Voyager spacecraft.  The limiting factor is radiation-induced degradation of the thermocouples, giving the effect of having a half-life of 35 years.
In order to be blasting out a kilowatt of power today, you'd need to fit the Voyager spacecraft with 16 RTGs rather than the three they've actually got, nearly doubling the mass.  This would put it far beyond the ability of any rocket of the time to launch: the Saturn V had been retired four years earlier, and the Delta IV Heavy was still 27 years in the future.

and even if it was, adding more RTG fuel wouldn't help as the fuel would all decay at the same rate and thus end up with a very similar useful lifetime of the radioactive core.

@jwenting That's not my understanding, though I'm admittedly a naif. I think the power of each is added together, so more RTGs means more power. Every "half-life" just halves the power output of each one, it doesn't limit the "useful lifetime", as they still produce power, just less of it. Launch with 16 x https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHW-RTG 1kW = 16 x 157 W = 2.5 kW. With a half-life of 35 years, then after 50 years you'd be down about 1 kW.

@Mark Do you have a ref for the 35 year halflife estimate? I find it entirely believable and logical, but annoyingly the wiki page only mentions the 87.7 years for the fuel, without mentioning the additional reduction due to degradation of the thermocouples. Google is also no help, or my Google-fu is weak today :(

I mention because I wonder whether this thermocouple degradation may not have been known or predicted at launch, but rather was discovered over time. In which case, it'd be another answer to the OP: if they had expected the 89.7 year half-life to have applied, they wouldn't have expected the power to have dropped this far until the year 2100 or so, so they certainly wouldn't have felt the need to add more RTGs!

@DewiMorgan, no explicit reference for the half-life, I just computed it from the available power output numbers plus seeing a mention that thermocouple damage had a half-life-like behavior.  Thermocouple degradation was expected and planned for, and the thermocouples on the Voyager spacecraft are actually failing slower than expected.

@Mark Cunning! Thanks :)

@DewiMorgan multiple RTGs would indeed produce more power but not increase the lifetime of the system. A larger RTG (past a certain limit) wouldn't produce more power, just add useless mass, and still not last longer. The ones installed on probes are of optimal size. And the size and mass of them dictates how many you can add before you exceed the capabilities of your launch vehicle.

@jwenting Since the limitation on the system lifetime appears to be power (once it no longer has sufficient power to transmit, it is effectively "dead"), how would having more power NOT increase the lifetime of the system?

An RTG produces energy using thermocouples. Those have to have one end exposed to the hot Pu-238, and the other and has to be as cold as possible. This limits how much fuel you can add to one RTG module. If you want more power, you have to add more RTG modules instead.

The reason was simple: "Four years — that was the prime mission."
I don't think anybody would have bet that the probes would stay operational for more than 4 decades. Sure: "If an engineer had a choice to put in a part that was 10 percent more expensive but wasn't something that was needed for a four-year mission, they just went ahead and did that." But there was simply no reason to put in fuel for 60 years.

more often than not that more expensive part would be chosen because it saved mass, thus saving mass for more sensors.

Four years may have been the on-paper criteria for calling it a successful mission, but the Voyagers were designed for the full twelve year Jupiter-Saturn-Uranus-Neptune sequence.
